# Объявление трёхмерного массива в Go

Tags: массивы, golang

У меня есть задача:

> Declare a three-dimensional array of the `float32` type with the size of 4 by 4 by 4 elements, assign 88.6 to its `[1][0][2]` element, and finally print the array to the console

Я объявил этот массив:

```
var array = [4][4][4]float32{

}
```

Но я не могу понять, как присвоить 88,6 его элементам `[1][0][2]`? Что это значит?
Назначить `[1][0][2]` каждому элементу в каждом массиве или только одному?

Также я получаю ошибку при попытке объявить элементы в этом массив:

```
88.6' (type untyped float) cannot be represented by the type [4]float32
```

И я не могу понять, почему.

Comment: Вы находитесь на русском SO, пожалуйста, составляйте вопросы именно на русском языке.

Comment: Вот как это работает, я то удивился, почему мой вопрос на английском вчера удалили...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Но я не могу понять, как присвоить 88,6 его элементам [1][0][2]

Не элементам [1][0][2] а одному элементу. Вам дан индекс, который в трехмерном массиве описывает один элемент. По первой оси его индекс 1, по второй 0, по третьей 2:

```
var array = [4][4][4]float32{}
array[1][0][2] = 88.6
fmt.Println(array)
```

Comment: Да, я уже понял. Решение было таким простым, прямо из условия, но я переусложнил задачу у себя в голове и не мог решить задачу из-за этого. В конце концов, я смог дойти до решения сам, но всё равно большое спасибо вам за ответ!